# How do I create test cases for given sample data in node.js?

Tags: node.js, node.js-stream

I was dong hackerrank test. My code provides required output by providing input but test shows it is a wrong answer. The link for test is https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/fullstack/challenges/testrun

Input Format

1 2 3

Output Format

2 3 7

Sample Input

1 9 9

Sample Output

? ? ?

Explanation

```
function processData(input) {
//Enter your code here
var number;
var main = "";
const aray = input.split(' ').map(Number)
for (var i = 0; i < aray.length; i++) {
        if (i === aray.length-1 && aray.length>1) {
            if (aray[i]*2 + 1 >= 9) {
            main += '?';
            }
            else {
            main += aray[i]*2 + 1
            }
        }
        else {
            if (aray[i+1] >= 9) {
            main += '?';
            main += ' '        
            }
            else {
            main += aray[i] + 1;
            main += ' '    

            }
        }
    }
console.log(main); 
}

process.stdin.resume();
process.stdin.setEncoding("ascii");
_input = '';
process.stdin.on("data", function (input) {
_input += input;
});

process.stdin.on("end", function () {
processData(_input);
});
```

How do I create test cases? If you know then please mention the mistake. Thanks

Comment: What exactly is the problem? What are the requirements for the solution?

Comment: @eol My code provides required output by providing input but test shows it is a wrong answer . By using input value of 1 2 3
it shows output of 2 3 7 and  by using input value of 1 9 9 it shows output of ? ? ?. It fulfill the requirements but the result shows it is a wrong answer

Comment: Can you post the link to the hackerrank challenge?

Comment: @eol https://www.hackerrank.com/contests/fullstack/challenges/testrun

Comment: link does not work unfortunately.

Comment: @eol link is working for me. May be you have to login first

Comment: @robot have you found any solution?

Comment: @eol after login into hackerrank.com link is working for me. Without login it gives 404

Answer (score -1):

If you just want to test a bunch of inputs, then write a bunch of function calls with different types of input.

Example:

```
processData([1, 2, 3]);
processData([4, 5, 6]);
processData([2, 2, 2]);
processData(["1", "2", "3"]);
// More tests here
```

If you want to automate providing input into your application, then something like [robotjs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/robotjs) might be useful.

If you're looking for a full on testing framework, then you can use mocha and chai. Here's an [article](https://blog.risingstack.com/getting-node-js-testing-and-tdd-right-node-js-at-scale/) on how to use them with node.